# Generate repeating row number based on partition column in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, window

I want to generate quarterly column shown below which is after every 4 records for each l_id number should change in pyspark. Before generating quarterly column will order data based on l_id and week columns.

[image]

Comment: You can use spark window functions to achieve the same functionality and if you have tried something sharing that will be great to start with.

Comment: I tried but not finding any solution. If you share example in window function will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I was thinking that there's a quaterly column already present in your dataframe but it seems you need a column that looks like quaterly. I don't think that is possible via Window function but here's a way to achieve this:

Assuming your current data is in df.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

split_col = split(df["week"],'month')
df = df.withColumn("quaterly", (split_col.getItem(1).cast("integer")/(df["sequence_change"] + lit(1))).cast("integer") + lit(1)).orderBy("l_id","week")
```

**Logic explanation:**
We are going to get the month number from `week` column values, cast it into an integer from string and divide it with the `sequence_change value + 1` and casting final value into an integer so you can just get an integer value for it with no decimals. At last adding 1 in it so that `quaterly` column starts with 1 instead of 0.